# Hide and show a image with Glide

Tags: android, image, show-hide, android-glide

I load ad image in a map of Google with Glide. I want hide/ the image on same condition. How can I do? there is a something as Visible and Invisible?

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
   .asBitmap()
   .load(url)
   .error(null)
   .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
         public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) { //code }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i dont find anything useful but myself do something like load empty.png that just have 24 * 24 emplty transparent for marker this make your marker seems invisible

Comment: I need to show and hide frequently, load a remote image is too expensive... I have tried onStop() method of SimpleTarget but don't work

Answer (score 0):

You can hold the view reference and change the visibility of it.

```
SimpleTarget imageView = new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
     public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) { //code }
};

Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
   .asBitmap()
   .load(url)
   .error(null)
   .into(imageView);
```

Then you can hide/show `imageView` using `setVisibility(View.GONE)` or `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` method

Comment: SimpleTarget imageView don't have setVisibility() as method. How can i invoce them ? :-O